# Easier XQuery statement

Tags: xpath, xquery

I ask myself if I could make the following statement simpler?
Can you help me out?

```
<Vorlesungsverzeichnis>
{
for $sws in distinct-values(doc('uni')//Vorlesung/SWS) 
order by $sws
return 
 <Vorlesungen SWS="{$sws}">
 {
   for $v in doc('uni')//Vorlesung[SWS=$sws]
   order by $v/Titel
   return <Vorlesung VorlNr="{$v/@VorlNr}" Titel="{$v/Titel}"></Vorlesung>
 }
 </Vorlesungen>
}
</Vorlesungsverzeichnis>
```

The source XML is available [here](http://dbkemper4-vm10.informatik.tu-muenchen.de:1999/uni.xml) and you could also try out the query [here](http://dbkemper4-vm10.informatik.tu-muenchen.de:1999/index.html#).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't think it can be simpler. It seems to do the job just fine and reads quite easy, so why would you want a simpler query?

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler way of expressing it. If you're worried about performance, then a naive processor will have O(n^2) time on this query, but a good processor will do join optimization - in some cases this will depend on you manually creating the right indexes.

Comment: Hm k, thought there is something better for group by. But ok if you like it it is fine to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XQuery 3.0 you can do the following:

```
<Vorlesungsverzeichnis>
{
  for $v in doc('uni')//Vorlesung
  order by $v/Titel
  group by $sws := $v/SWS
  return <Vorlesungen SWS="{$sws}">{$v}</Vorlesungen>
}
</Vorlesungsverzeichnis>
```